# no sound android x86

Tags: android, alsa, android-x86

I have currently installed Android x86 onto my HP Pavilion dv2617us laptop. There is no sound at all, but every so often, the mute button turns from blue to red, and vice versa (basically muting and unmuting). The speakers pop when this happens, and it's very annoying. If I try to increase the sound using the buttons, it crashes the current app that I am in.

Is this a driver problem? I have done the following commands.

```
root@x86 # alsa_ctl init
Found Hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Conexant CX . . . .
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
```

It detected soundcard, which is a step in the right direction.

I have also tried to add in `alsa_amixer set PCM 100 unmute` into `init.sh`, but to no avail. I'm all out of ideas.

Suggestions, anyone?

Note: On a physical computer, *not* in Virtualbox.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that sound is supposed to be supported in this distribution?

Comment: Have u tried this http://ronubo.blogspot.in/2012/03/enabling-sound-on-android-x86-devices.html

Comment: Does sound work with a 'normal' Linux?